# Why doesn't Mathematica evaluate the function I created?

Tags: function-construction

For some reason when I evaluate the function which I created I only get a recreation of the argument I am putting into the function. However, my friend ran the same thing and was able to actually determine the result. Why is this happening to me?
[image]

Comment: Please paste your code into the question.  From the image it looks like there could be a space between "expected" and "_", which would break it, but we could spot this easily from the code.

Comment: Why are the underscores of different lengths (it seems)?

Comment: That too, and there shouldn't be a space between the variable and the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can not do anything with your input because you have not followed some basic rules:

[Defining Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

[Making Definitions for Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html)

[Blank](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)

see also:

[How to | Work with Variables and Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithVariablesAndFunctions.html)

```
percentError[observed_, expected_] := (observed - expected)/expected

percentError[50.5, 50]
```

> 0.01

Attempt to recognize the difference between your and my input.

Check out also:

[How tos](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HowToTopics.html)

A "How to" describes how to carry out particular tasks with the Wolfram Language, giving step-by-step instructions for common cases.